# Spring batch for rules

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch. I need to run a nightly batch process that:

1. reads records from table A,
2. for each record in table A,

   1. run about 10 business rules with logic involve reading data from the database (in each rule) and
   2. write into table B in each rule, the result of the rule

I also need some way to running the rules on demand for a smaller subset of records from table A.  Is Spring Batch a good option? Can I put the logic for data access and business logic inside an `ItemProcessor`?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Here is what I have done :

1. Created a `DiscountReader` that extends `JdbcCursorItemReader` that fetches discount programs based on dates and other criteria _ returns objects of type DiscountObj
2. Created a `SalesProcessor` that implements `ItemProcessor`, within which I have (a) `SalesReader` that should read a different set of tables to get Sales records that match the parameters from the current DiscountObj (b) SalesWriter that should write the data fetched by `SalesReader` to another table.

The parameters for the query executed by `SalesReader` is dynamic since it has to be extracted from the current `DiscountObj`. How can I set the values into the `PreparedStatement` for the `SalesReader`? I tried using the `PreparedStatementSetter`, however, the query is getting executed even before the values are set.

Any help/pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We're starting to have a conversation here.  Can you break the update piece out into a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a very common Spring Batch use case.  Spring Batch's chunk based step reads each item, passes it to a processor, then once the number of items per chunk has been processed, writes all of the items out.

Using a `JdbcCursorItemReader` to read the input, developing your own `ItemProcessor` to apply the rules, and using the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` to write the output is what I would expect.